# Не устанавливается Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors

Tags: android, драйвер, эмулятор, amd

Когда запускаю эмулятор, меня просят установить Драйвер для АМД, я жму ОК. Но при установке терминал начинается бесконечно открываться и закрываться, а в самом окне установки непонятные символы. Виртуализация в BIOS включена, HyperV отключен, как и рекомендуется на сайте Android Studio

[image: Термин так открывается бесконечно, даже если меняю окно, закрывая Andoid Studio]
[image: Ошибка при запуске эмулятора]

Comment: Столкнулась с такой же проблемой((
Вы ее решили?

Comment: Да, там нужно было удалить часть кода в каком-то файле, но уже не помню, если честно.
Если вам очень нужно, поищу